# Jasmine Matching Return Value

Tags: undefined, jasmine, matcher

I got some typical jasmine code such as:

```
expect(actual).someMatcher(expected);
```

Is there a way to determine whether this matching succeed or failed (programmatically)? Depending on the result, I might want to do a certain operation afterwards. For example, if it fails, write the actual to disk.

Using the matcher's return value doesn't seem to work. It always returns undefined.

Comment: Could you please post the test code and the relevant source code?

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way would be to write your own [reporter](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/jsdoc/symbols/jasmine.Reporter.html).

Alternatively, within a spec, `this` is the spec. `this.results()` would return the results, and you can get all you need by looking at the `items_` property of the value of `this.results()`.

Comment: With jasmine 2.0, the `this` in a spec is no longer the spec object itself, but a dummy place to hang variables you want to be available to `beforeEach`, `it`, and `afterEach`. So a reporter is probably the best bet now.